# While creating object in Javascript using Object constructor function, Why the created object is in square bracket and not in curly braces?

Tags: javascript

Creating object using Object constructor function as below

```
const obj = new Object(42);
console.log(obj);
```

According to MDN it creates object of a Type that corresponds to the given value.
Getting result in console as:

> [Number: 42]

Why its in square braces and not in curly braces as in

> {Number : 42}

Comment: That's just how the console shows you the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think `{Number: 42}` would mean that it is an object with a property `Number`, as if you could do `obj.Number`, which would give you 42. Also, you could copy and paste it in the console and get a different object. So it literally represents a different object.

On the other hand, `[Number: 42]` is not meaningful in JS, so it works well as kind of ascii-art for humans to get an idea about the object.

Note that the output probably depends on the browser/JS engine. Firefox and Chrome both give me

> Number {42}